# Doctrine2 - Type timestamp - Default value

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, timestamp

For some reasons, I need to have tables with `TIMESTAMP` fields.

I created my own Timestamp Type (`Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type`), it works fine.

But when I try to update my database structure, I got this.

**Command line**

```
ede80:~>php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
Updating database schema...

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHANGE DATE_CREATION DATE_CREATION timestamp DEFAULT NULL'

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'DATE_CREATION'
```

**SQL Query**

If I execute the following query on the database, I works :

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHANGE DATE_CREATION DATE_CREATION timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**ORM.YML**

But when I try to change it in `MyTable.orm.yml`, like this :

```
    dateCreation:
        type: timestamp
        nullable: true
        column: DATE_CREATION
        options:
            default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The executed query is

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHANGE DATE_CREATION DATE_CREATION timestamp DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

And it fails.

How can I set a working default value, so my database's structure can be up to date ?
I already tried to set `options: default` to `0`, `NULL`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `00:00:01`...

PHP 5.3.3
MySQL 5.1.63

**Here is the Timestamp Type**

I think that convert*() aren't that well.

```
<?php
namespace CNAMTS\PHPK\CoreBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 */
class Timestamp extends Type
{
    const TIMESTAMP = 'timestamp';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getDoctrineTypeMapping('TIMESTAMP');
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value === null) ? 0 : new \DateTime($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value === null) ? 0 : $value->format(\DateTime::W3C);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::TIMESTAMP;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use DATETIME type?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Comment: I have already read this page, but I can't, it's a standard in my job, unfortunately.. I know, this is stupid.

Comment: You can try to define your property as Doctrine's `datetime` type and maybe it will work because `datetime` is interpreted as `TIMESTAMP` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thx for your tip, I effectively tried that, but they are stored as `Datetime` field, and I need `Timestamp` fields. I use MySQL actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to have more than one timestamp field in the table.

You need to have your own Timestamp type defined and added in **AppKernel.php** :

```
public function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    /**
     * SQL type TIMESTAMP
     */
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('timestamp', 'My\CoreBundle\Doctrine\Type\Timestamp');
    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('TIMESTAMP', 'timestamp');
}
```

In your entity definition, **MyEntity.orm.yml** :

```
 dateCreation:
        type: timestamp
        nullable: false
        column: DATE_CREATION
        columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    dateModification:
        type: timestamp
        nullable: false
        column: DATE_MODIFICATION
        columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And in the entity **MyEntity.php**, have a prePersist :

```
public function doPrePersist()
{
    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
}
```

That's how I made it work :-)
Thx all for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I tried that and it worked for me :

```
dateCreation:
        type: datetime
        version: true
        column: DATE_CREATION
```

with

```
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2"
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Thx for that tip, I didn't know it.

It could work in my case, but I need at least 2 TIMESTAMP fields, and unfortunately, with this, it's impossible due to some DBMS reasons (I use MySQL 5.1.63, this limitation has been removed in MySQL 5.6.5).

So I'll keep my first workaround :-/

But nice try !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if my answer still helps, but maybe it will help someone in the future. The way we did it is only thru mappings, no extra types (timestamp is allowed by Doctrine). There's the solution:

```
dateAdd:
     type: datetime
     column: date_add
     columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
     options:
         default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
editDate:
     type: datetime
     column: date_edit
     columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
     options:
         default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The column definition makes sure it will be created properly, and `options` settings make sure that when you run `doctrine:schema:validate`, you will see it is in sync (it is used for cross-checking the defaults with current definition).

Same, if you'd like to make those columns nullable, you have to change `columnDefinition` and add `nullable: false`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had a problem with this solution. Doctrine tries to save "null" to the date fields on insert/update.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to remove the quote around CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. The sql query is executed well without the quotes .

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHANGE DATE_CREATION DATE_CREATION timestamp [NULL|NOT NULL] DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: How ? I don't execute the queries myself, I let Doctrine handle it.

Comment: Can you post your Timestamp Type?

Comment: if you use symfony, why do you not declare your TIMESTAMP like this?
fields:
      myDate:
            type: datetime
            version: true