# In PHP Mysql int, bigint and timestamp in which datatype field is used store timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I created a column (`created_at`) to store a timestamp, but I am confused whether I should use int, bigint or timestamp data type to store the timestamp.

Please clarify it in detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [datetime vs timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

Comment: obviously you have to use the "timestamp" data type store timestamp data

Comment: @arun--> I saw that int is used to store timestamp.

http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/6027/why-use-int-instead-of-datetime-or-timestamp-in-the-039users039-table

Answer (score 0):

You must use `TIMESTAMP` because:

In Timestamp values are converted from the current time zone to UTC while storing, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone when retrieved.

And for more detail refer this: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.php

Comment: but i think it would be create problem after 2038.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @Trliok That problem only exists on 32 bit systems, which, are practically nonexistent for any computers made in the last 2-3 years. By the time 2038 comes around (and even way before that) it's very unlikely anything would still be using 32 bit processors. I would assume it would be like trying to find a 16 bit processor today, which were once the standard back in the mid-90's.

Comment: @mike--according to you which datatype is best?