# MySql TIMESTAMP column is auto updated. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table created with this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `data` TEXT,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE InnoDB;
```

But when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table`, I get:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Why the timestamp column being assigned **ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** by default? I do not know how to get rid of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to php my admin, change 'default' option to As defined and select first option in attributes section of 'timestamp' column of 'test_table'

Comment: using **phpmyadmin** and altering this everytime is a heck, I have 25-30 tables created like this. And may create more in future. Is there any SQL way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a datetime field instead

[Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

> Timestamps in MySQL generally used to track changes to records, and
>   are often updated every time the record is changed. If you want to
>   store a specific value you should use a datetime field.
>
> If you meant that you want to decide between using a UNIX timestamp or
>   a native MySQL datetime field, go with the native format. You can do
>   calculations within MySQL that way  ("SELECT DATE_ADD(my_datetime,
>   INTERVAL 1 DAY)") and it is simple to change the format of the value
>   to a UNIX timestamp ("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime)") when you
>   query the record if you want to operate on it with PHP.

Comment: can I safely alter my table.columns to *datetime* from *timestamp*? please note, my tables have data.

Comment: Yes, you can. In general though, I would *highly* recommend testing any table changes with production data in them on a test database.

Answer (score 4):

If you want that to your `timestamp` will be not added automatically `ON UPDATE` you have to define it like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
   ...
   `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ...
```

Comment: can I omit the **DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** part?

Comment: nevermind. just checked and nope, I can't! However, I used **DEFAULT 0** to prevent this.

Comment: you can use instead `DEFAULT NULL`,  or use  `datetime` column type  LIKE: timestamp datetime  DEFAULT NULL as @thaspius suggested

Comment: Declare the column as `TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL` if you want it nullable and no auto behavior.