# Current_Timestamp on different time zone

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE options(
  id MEDIUM INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

however.. after inserting a value like:

```
INSERT INTO options VALUES(0,'test@test.com',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I got the created_at column with this value : **10:29** but right now the time is **16:29**.

I believe that's because the server/db is located in the US and I'm in Brazil.

Is there a way to get **my** current time when inserting values into the table?

Comment: This may help a bit: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp

Comment: you should use the `TIMESTAMP` data type because `TIMESTAMP` support `time_zone` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp

Comment: Why not make the table definition `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` so [it does what you want](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) all by itself? Then when you `SELECT`, use [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).