# How to add 1 hour to currrent_timestamp in mysql which is the default value?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I have a database with timestamp field which takes current timestamp by default, but I have problem with the time, like if I insert the row at 9:00 it will take 8 as timestamp.

So my question is how to make current_timestamp in that table add one hour by default? I know you can do it with php but I prefer pure mysql solution.

I have a problem with the server timezone but I don't want to change it, since I am afraid this might affect other databases on server, while I want to change timestamp only in one database.

Comment: It probably might be because the MySQL server is in a different timezone

Comment: it sounds like problem with server timezone, so check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Is their a way without changing the server timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

Comment: @Strawberry this is not what I need

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply you cannot do `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR`, but you can define a trigger instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_dt_table BEFORE INSERT ON your_table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.datetime_field = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
END
```

And remove any default values of that field (i.e. make it `NULL` by default) in order to avoid contradictions.

Comment: I want to add that if it's a timestamp field it must be created with "fieldname timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL"

Comment: Also, I tested the trigger, it worked without the "BEGIN"

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table_name values (DATE_ADD(now() , INTERVAL 1 HOUR));
```

Comment: I want to add 1 hour by default to the my timestamp field

Answer (score 0):

This actually works just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  password_rest_tokens (
  token char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  expires datetime DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

if you run an insert

```
INSERT INTO password_rest_tokens (token ) VALUES (12345);
```

You'll see the expires is set to 1 hours ahead upon insertion.