# Create Transaction on MariaDB to set expiry time for ip blacklist

Tags: sql, mariadb

The question I used to help build this transaction is here:
[How to add 1 hour to currrent_timestamp in mysql which is the default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955039/how-to-add-1-hour-to-currrent-timestamp-in-mysql-which-is-the-default-value)

I'm trying to create a transaction in my database to fill in the `allowed` column in my mariadb database table `blacklisted_ips`. I want the `allowed` column to be an hour after my `added` column which has a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Here is my transaction so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_blacklisted_ips BEFORE INSERT ON blacklisted_ips FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.allowed=NOW()+INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
END;
```

The error message I'm getting is the following:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE blacklisted_ips (
    ip_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ip_add varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    added timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    allowed timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ip_id)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154158/mysql-how-do-i-use-delimiters-in-triggers

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql

Comment: @BillKarwin You're absolutely right, it was my lack of delimiters, but that was not immediately clear because it's hard to see when none of the examples show triggers. I would love to give you the answer on this one if you want to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, there's an ambiguity between the `;` that terminates a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, and the possible `;` characters that terminate individual statements in the body of the trigger.

The error you got is confusing:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Normally a syntax error includes the text of the statement *following* the position where the syntax parser got confused. But in your case, it got confused at `;`, thinking it was the end of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. Therefore the error occurs at the termination; there is no text following the error as far as the parser is concerned.

The same issue affects `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION`.

To fix the ambiguity, MySQL client supports a [builtin command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) to change the DELIMITER, so you can change it to something distinct from any sequence of characters that appear in the body of your routine.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_blacklisted_ips BEFORE INSERT ON blacklisted_ips 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.allowed=NOW()+INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
END ;;
```

Alternatively, since in your case the trigger is a single-statement trigger, you don't need a `BEGIN...END` block at all. This way you can skip changing the DELIMITER, because the `;` that terminates your `CREATE TRIGGER` is the same `;` that terminates the single statement of the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_blacklisted_ips BEFORE INSERT ON blacklisted_ips 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.allowed=NOW()+INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

P.S.: This is documented with an example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html