# Symfony2 form datetime and datetimepicker

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm currently trying to add a form field with datetimepicker, as i'm submiting im getting the following error

```
This value is not valid.    pesagem1    
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[pesagem1] = 27/04/2016 23:59
Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
Unable to reverse value for property path "pesagem1": DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/04/2016 23:59) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/04/2016 23:59) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
Caused by:
Exception
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/04/2016 23:59) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

this is my entity + form

//entity

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") */
private $pesagem1;
```

//FORM

```
        ->add('pesagem1','datetime', array(
                'widget' => "single_text",
                'html5' => false,
                'date_format'=>"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",
                'attr'=>array(
                    'class'=>'datetimepickz form-control',
                    'style' => 'width: 70%',
                    'data-format'=>"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
                )
            )
        )
```

js + twig

```
$('.datetimepickz').datetimepicker({

        locale: moment.locale('pt')

    });


<div class="form-group">

                        <label>Primeira Pesagem</label>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envira"></i></span>
                            {{ form_widget(form.pesagem1) }}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {{ form_errors(form.pesagem1) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Seams like the string is "correct" according to symfony2 profiler, already tried with date format dd/mm/yyy hh:mm , d/m/Y hh:mm. and all returns the same problem.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.
ty

Answer (score 0):

after reading [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp?rq=1)

i changed my date format, and everything seams ok now.

```
$('.datetimepickz').datetimepicker({
        locale: moment.locale('pt'),
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
    });
```