# SQL - Best way to record multiple date/times and compute time difference.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a project where I'm recording times into my database, and I want to store the difference between the two times as well. I implemented them using the SQL object: TIMESTAMP and recorded the timestamp using

```
TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(),CURTIME())
```

These store fine. Now I want to compute the difference between the two times, but it looks like PHP's TIMESTAMPDIFF() function takes in datetime objects instead of timestamp objects. There are a few ways I could move on from here, but I was wondering if there's a preferred way that SQL developers record and compute time differences. I need both the date and the time, so that I can get the difference accurate to the second.

Comment: Is the difference computed between two columns which already exist in your table?  If so I might opt for computing the difference when you query, rather than storing a computed column which wastes space.

Comment: OK. I'm still unsure the best way to store and compute these things though.

Comment: Are you recording one timestamp or two of them (neglecting the differences) ?  Can you show us a sample table, along with the differences you want to compute?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a 2 part question and is definitely duplicates of other questions on SO. A quick search produced a SO question that over 1000 people voted for `DATETIME` as the storage type ([Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp))

The main difference between `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` in mysql is that `TIMESTAMP` will store that date at UTC and `datetime` will store your specific value.  So if you don't need to translate between time zones, or have multiple time zones etc.  Stick with `DATETIME` and the you don't have to convert or cast or anything.

As far as getting the difference between 2 `datetimes` or 2 `timestamps` I am certain their are SO questions on here I suggest searching a little more.