# MYSQL where with date time field

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is the wrong with the query? It's not following the date condition. It's returning all the data and I want data less than the mentioned date.

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `user`.`firstname`, `user`.`lastname`, `user`.`organisation_name`, `user`.`type`, `user_info`.`profile_picture`, `user_info`.`logo`, `user`.`email`
FROM (`messages`) JOIN
     `user`
     ON `user`.`user_id` = `messages`.`from_id` JOIN
     `user_info`
     ON `user_info`.`uid` = `messages`.`from_id`
WHERE `messages`.`from_id` = '4' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '24572' AND 
      `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47' OR
      `messages`.`from_id` = '24572' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '4' AND 
     `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47'
ORDER BY `msg_id` DESC
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Share your error message

Comment: its not following the date condition

Comment: its returning all the data and i want data less than the mentioned date

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can get all messages by user as a sender or reciever. Can you try below, please?

```
SELECT
    `messages`.*, `user`.`firstname`,
    `user`.`lastname`,
    `user`.`organisation_name`,
    `user`.`type`,
    `user_info`.`profile_picture`,
    `user_info`.`logo`,
    `user`.`email`
FROM
    `messages`
JOIN `user` ON `user`.`user_id` = `messages`.`from_id`
JOIN `user_info` ON `user_info`.`uid` = `messages`.`from_id`
WHERE
    (
        `messages`.`from_id` = '4'
        AND `messages`.`to_id` = '24572'
        AND `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47'
    )
OR (
    `messages`.`from_id` = '24572'
    AND `messages`.`to_id` = '4'
    AND `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47'
)
ORDER BY
    `messages`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: i did the above but its not following the date condition

Comment: no its not giving me the error.it is returning the wrong data.its not following the date less than condition in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing brackets "(" and ")":

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `user`.`firstname`, `user`.`lastname`, `user`.`organisation_name`, `user`.`type`, `user_info`.`profile_picture`, `user_info`.`logo`, `user`.`email`
FROM `messages` JOIN
     `user`
     ON `user`.`user_id` = `messages`.`from_id` JOIN
     `user_info`
     ON `user_info`.`uid` = `messages`.`from_id`
WHERE `messages`.`from_id` = '4' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '24572' AND 
      `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47' OR
      `messages`.`from_id` = '24572' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '4' AND 
     `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47'
ORDER BY `msg_id` DES
```

And it will be helpful if you share error message and also take care about your 'AND' and 'OR' condition, as they don't have brackets so there priority will be different then what you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `user`.`firstname`, `user`.`lastname`, `user`.`organisation_name`, `user`.`type`, `user_info`.`profile_picture`, `user_info`.`logo`, `user`.`email`
FROM (`messages`) JOIN
     `user`
     ON `user`.`user_id` = `messages`.`from_id` JOIN
     `user_info`
     ON `user_info`.`uid` = `messages`.`from_id`
WHERE `messages`.`from_id` = '4' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '24572' AND 
      `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47' OR
      `messages`.`from_id` = '24572' AND
      `messages`.`to_id` = '4' AND 
     `messages`.`time_sent` <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47'
ORDER BY `messages`.`msg_id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Categorize the `AND` and `OR` with the `()` brackets** AND make sure table field type

---

```
SELECT messages.*, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.organisation_name, user.type, user_info.profile_picture, user_info.logo, user.email 
FROM messages 
JOIN user ON user.user_id = messages.from_id 
JOIN user_info ON user_info.uid = messages.from_id 
WHERE (messages.from_id = '4' AND messages.to_id = '24572' AND messages.time_sent <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47')
    OR (messages.from_id = '24572' AND messages.to_id = '4' AND messages.time_sent <= '2016-06-23 12:41:47')
ORDER BY msg_id DESC
```

---

Read [MySQL: Combining the AND and OR Conditions](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php) and [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

---

**Example**
[image]

Comment: i did the above but its not following the date condition

Comment: @AshokJutlawar try with `2016-06-23 00:00:00`

Comment: no i cannot change time its stored in the database and i have to use that value only

Comment: @AshokJutlawar try like this `messages.time_sent >=2016-06-23 12:41:47`

Comment: @AshokJutlawar If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)