# Most appropriate SQL and Java data types for storing date and time

Tags: java, mysql, date, time, java-8

Apologies in advance for the somewhat broad question.

What are the most appropriate MySQL and Java data types for handling date and times with the following format: yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss

I need to be able to convert a String representation of the date & time into the given Date Format as well as then store that date&time in the database. I then need to do the reverse and convert the MySQL date & time into the corresponding Java representation

I have read a lot of questions about Date, DateTime, ZonedDateTime but none of these seem to work at all well.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but it was not successful, though I forget why.

Comment: So you tried java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Yep, I tried exactly what was recommended in that post. I think it was some kind of conversion error.
I have heard that Java 8 comes with better ways to handle dates & times so I thinking there might be a new, better solution.

Comment: You will be able to talk to a DB just fine with a slightly older version of Java! Was the error an SQL error or Java error

Comment: @LucasAmos "I have heard that Java 8 comes with better ways to handle dates & times" Yes, cleaner concepts, better date arithmetic but these will help your problem with the mysql as much as a "Ferrari-red paint coat" will help a truck run better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What are the most appropriate MySQL and Java data types for handling date and times with the following format: yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss*

The most appropriate MySQL type is DATETIME. See [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp).

The corresponding Java type to use in your persistence layer (jdbc type) is java.sql.Timestamp. See [Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

*I need to be able to convert a String representation of the date & time into the given Date Format as well as then store that date&time in the database.*

The correct transformation is: `java.lang.String -> java.util.Date -> java.sql.Timestamp`.

- `java.lang.String -> java.util.Date`:

`Date javaDatetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss").parse(stringDatetime);`

- `java.util.Date -> java.sql.Timestamp`:

`Timestamp jdbcDatetime = new Timestamp(javaDatetime.getTime());`

*I then need to do the reverse and convert the MySQL date & time into the corresponding Java representation*

Do the reverse path:

- `java.sql.Timestamp -> java.util.Date`:

`Date javaDatetime = new java.util.Date(jdbcDatetime.getTime());`

- `java.lang.Date -> java.util.String`:

`String stringDatetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss").format(javaDatetime);`

I've been concise. You have to pay attention about the use of SimpleDateFormat (e.g. cache an instance which has been initialized with applyPattern and setLenient).

**Update for Java 8**
Some enhancements have been done on jdbc types (see [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html)) that simplify conversions. For the case illustrated above you can use [toLocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--) and [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-) to convert from java.sql.Timestamp to the new java.time.LocalDateTime and back.

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated ... We have better alternatives starting from java 8 and jdbc 4.2+

Answer (score 10):

In your case, the mysql type would be `DATETIME` and the Java 8 type would be `LocalDateTime`.

#### Conversion between String and LocalDateTime

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAsString, fmt);
String dateAsString = dateTime.format(fmt);
```

#### Interaction with the database (JDBC 4.2 compliant driver)

If the driver is compliant with JDBC 4.2 (the latest version of mysql Java connector should be compliant), you can do:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class);
preparedStatement.setObject(1, dateTime);
```

#### Non compliant driver

If your driver is not compliant yet, you would store/retrieve the `DATETIME` field as a `java.sql.Timestamp` like you did before Java 8.

You can then convert to/from `LocalDateTime` with:

```
//from LocalDateTime to Timestamp:
java.time.LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAsString, fmt);
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);

//from Timestamp to LocalDateTime:
java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp();
java.time.LocalDateTime dateTime = ts.toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format your code by this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date dateUtil = DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateEcheance);
java.sql.Date dateSql = new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime());
```

I hope that you will help you.

Comment: Thanks, what does the dateEcheance variable refer to?