# wrong time format in exported excel sheet

Tags: php, excel

I do an excel export of some data from database.

Date value in database: `2017-02-15 15:31:54` (timestamp)

I set format of excel field like this:

```
setFormat('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

But the value i get in my excel sheet is `16.02.2017 14:31:54`.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

**Edit:**

If I echo the value of the variable which I insert to excel field, the output is correct. But in excel then there is the wrong value.

Comment: Check something here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp It seems that TimeStamp is a little different from what you are expecting.

Comment: Try casting to a date time format before exporting: SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(colonne_timestamp) as valeur_datetime FROM table;

Comment: I cast the date before inserting into excel field to `d.m.Y H:i:s`, but I have the same effect, that the day and hour is wrong.

Comment: edited question

Comment: I found a solution. The Excel field could not handle the time values in datetime format. I `setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)` of the excel field. Now the value is displayed correctly in excel.