# TIMESTAMP or DATETIME in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am living in Germany, but want to test a website in the US. I will be using a MySQL database, where the current time will be saved and I heard that TIMESTAMP can take timezones into account, so I'm not sure whether to use TIMESTAMP or DATETIME in MySQL.

All of the entries will be created by people in the US and of course, every user should see the time in their current timezone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

Comment: my two cents is to use datetime