# MySQL datetime with different time zones

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a `DateTime` object in `mysql` database containing for example this `datetime "2017-08-14 18:06:40"` and the `server/mysql` default timezone is USA so when i insert a `datetime` it goes in US time zone .

My problem is when a user from let's say Europe select that datetime , it will be different because of the timing difference isn't so ?

How do I solve this problem. I want the user in Europe to get the datetime relative to their timezone

I found from searching this

```
CONVERT_TZ(`comment_date`,@@global.time_zone,@@session.time_zone) AS comment_date,
```

Then I found that you need to set `@@session.time_zone` its not detected automatically

So how do we solve this and what are the option and techniques that sites or `apps` uses to unification `datetime` across countries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change the datatype to `timestamp` instead of `datetime` if you want it to represent an instant moment in time regardless of timezone where it was saved. `Timestamp` is always saved as UTC while `datetime` represents a local date and time and does not contain any zone information.

See this question for more information: [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

See also [Mysql reference manual regarding datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Comment: will you can use datetime object just dont insert the value ,set the default value to current time stamp ,,and set the mysql to UTC time , then parse the date on client side to the default timezone