# JPA - How to get a CREATION_DATE column work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
ID_EMAIL  bigint(20)
ID_NEWSLETTER  bigint(20)
SUBSCRIPTION_DATE timestamp  NULLABLE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and a JPA class like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="SUBSCRIPTION_DATE", updatable = false)
private Date subscriptionDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_EMAIL",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private AnagraficaIscritti anagraficaIscritti;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Newsletter
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_NEWSLETTER", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Newsletter newsletter;
```

When I insert an object in other tables the field SUBSCRIPTION_DATE is always updated . This is wrong because I'd like to store only "creation_date" so I'd like to prevent to being updated every time.
So, for example, if I am inserting record 51 all the previous column SUBSCRIPTION_DATE record are updated !!!

```
|       48 |            34 | 2017-10-11 12:09:42 |
|       49 |            34 | 2017-10-11 12:09:42 |
|       50 |            34 | 2017-10-11 12:09:42 |
|       51 |            34 | 2017-10-11 12:09:42 |
+----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Any hints?

the code of the update that could cause the problem should be this:

```
for (Newsletter item : newsletterItem ) {
boolean isIscritto = false;
for (AnagraficaIscritti iscItem : item.getAnagraficaIscrittis() ) {
    if (iscItem.getIdEmail() == iscritto.getIdEmail())
        isIscritto = true;      
}
if (!isIscritto) {  
    item.getAnagraficaIscrittis().add(iscritto);            
    em.persist(item);           
}

}
```

I think that when I persist Newsletter object all the column SUBSCRIPTION_DATE are updated at the same value for the same newsletter

I also tried to modify the SQL declaration in

SUBSCRIPTION_DATE timestamp  NULLABLE DEFAULT NULL

when it updates the SUBSCRIPTION_DATE updates all the rows to NULL.

Thanks

Comment: can you share you code that updates the object?

Comment: I think this @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) will always set the TimeStamp

Comment: @Code.IT that simply tells it to store it as a TIMESTAMP. A field is only persisted as what is in the object being persisted/merged.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html Change the column type to datetime or disable auto-update for the timestamp column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

Comment: I added the code that could cause the problem. The definition of the column in mysql should be correct, because NULLABLE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP store current timestamp ONLY when insert new row NOT ON UPDATE

Comment: I also tried the annotation @CreationTimestamp but same result :(