# Equivalent of Datetime2 of mysql in mssql

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the equivalent of Datetime2 of mysql in mssql ?

Comment: it's probably `DateTime`. you can check here for more information.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp

Comment: MySql documentation doesn't seem to mention `DateTime2`. Sql Server does have `DateTime2` - are you sure you didn't get your databases mixed up?

Answer (score 5):

> **MySQL 5.7** has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and
>   TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision:
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html

> **Datetime2**
>   Precision, scale    0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default
>   precision is 7 digits https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql

`Datetime2` is a term used in MS SQL Server. A MS SQL Server column defined as `datetime2(6)` is the equivalent to a MySQL 5.7 `datetime` or `timestamp` column.

Comment: Would downvoters please identify the incorrect facts. Then I could address their concerns. All I have sought to do is find the closet match of date/time precision in 2 databases