# Store current time in timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field named: **last_dl** in MySQL database.
I don't know what type it should be. At first I want to store current time in it, and in future, after a user request, check if 72 hours passed. then do something.

I'm confused what type to choose. Should I use MYSQL functions or PHP functions? Do I need timestamp or not. How to convert back that timestamp in database?

Comment: I'm confused too. I wasn't just a minute ago.

Comment: @Andreas Kidding?

Comment: sql has datediff function but only you know how you are going to interrogate it and how use that data...

Comment: you can use `datetime`, `timestamp`  type for that column

Comment: What's wrong with using a datetime datatype in your database?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) field in mySql. Then from php you can check if 72 hours have passed since then.

```
$dbdate = strtotime($datefromdb);
if (time() - $dbdate > 60 * 60 * 72) {
    // 72 hours passed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, store the value of `last_dl` in the database with the  `DATETIME` format.

Then all you need is run query in database and the PHP will get the result ready:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`last_dl`, NOW())) as 'hours diff',
IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`last_dl`, NOW())) > 72,'YES' , 'NO') as 'age check passed'
FROM `table_name`
;
```

Result is:
Assume the `last_dl` has value `'2017-12-11 15:45:57.005678'`

> hours diff    age check passed
>   89    YES
>   99    YES
>   65    NO
>   75    YES
>   41    NO
>   51    NO
>   17    NO

See it live: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7c11d/1

**EDIT**  Tuned the example ;)