# Graphing the timestamp and data from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, chart.js

Hello im new to coding and currently im facing an issue with graphing the timestamp from mysql database. im using xampp . i was able to graph the other elements in the table except the timestamp of every data.

Comment: the time format is like this.. 

2018-02-21 09:59:30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use the datetime or timestamp data type in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to chart quantitative values (numbers).  As @bar points out in his comment, the time format is `2018-02-21 09:59:30` - this is not a number you can plus, minus, etc.

Use the [MySQL `TIMESTAMP(datetime_field)` function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestamp-function.php).