# Maximum int value result function time()

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save the value returned by the php "time();" function in a mysql table.
When I create an int field within a table, the maximum length of the int value is requested.
I wanted to ask you what value suggest to include in the type declaration of int.

I ask you this because, by saving the digit in int, it will be easy to compare it with other results of the "time ();" (which if I understand correctly, it always returns an int value).

Thank you

Comment: [MySQL has few int types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). To accommodate UNIX timestamp you need at least INT, after 2030 maybe even more.

Comment: [Should I use the datetime or timestamp data type in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql)

Comment: What are you planning on using the UNIX timestamp for? Is it just to store arbitrary dates in DB? There is a rather narrow band of use cases for storing UNIX timestamps in DB as integers.

Answer (score 2):

As of [PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So you're better of with using `DATETIME` type in your MySQL database and saving the timestamp after you convert it into valid format. For that I'd use `DateTime`. Even better if you just use `new DateTime` instead of `time()`, as `DateTime` takes time in constructor, which by default is `now`:

> `public DateTime::__construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )`

If you were to use Doctrine 2, it would have been enough. Otherwise, you must format your DateTime object before inserting:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will produce something like

```
2019-04-30 15:34:16
```

which is completely valid format for your `DATETIME` type in your mysql database.

If you need to compare other DateTime objects, you can always use [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

> `public DateTime::diff ( DateTimeInterface $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = FALSE ] ) : DateInterval`

This will be enough for smart and representable operations with DateTimes and their comparison.

---

**EDIT:**

As you wrote

> Ok, I converted the db field into a "DATETIME" field. But now I can't compare the result of the table field with a DateTime () object. Do you know how I can convert the table field to be comparable with a DateTime () object?

You need to create the `DateTime` object from the data you have in your database. It is achieved by using [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> `public static DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] ) : DateTime`

So what you do is:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-04-30 15:34:16');
```

and *voila!*

Comment: I agree that DateTime is better to store dates, but OP is asking about storing UNIX timestamp specifically. MySQL has timestamp type too: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: @Dharman OP is asking about comparing things, he just doesn't know he can compare DateTime objects yet.

Comment: `DateTime::diff` will get you the difference between 2 dates. You can compare the objects directly with each other. e.g. `if($dt < $dt2)`

Comment: @AlexKarshin Ok, I converted the db field into a "DATETIME" field. But now I can't compare the result of the table field with a DateTime () object.
Do you know how I can convert the table field to be comparable with a DateTime () object?