# Magento 2 Collection Date Filter out by one hour

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, magento, magento2

I have an issue where I filter a collection by date and the item I expect to get is not being returned in the collection, however if I print out the SQL that the collection uses and run that against my database the item is returned.

```
$from = new \DateTime($lsDate);
$orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect(['grand_total', 'created_at'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId())
        ->setPageSize(10)
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

$from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') // Lets say this is 2019-08-06 15:33:00
$this->logger->info(count($orders)); // This is 0
```

If I print out the SQL that this generates it looks something like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`grand_total`, `main_table`.`created_at` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`created_at` >= '2019-08-06 15:33:21')
```

The orders `created_at` date that should be returned is `2019-08-06 15:34:00`.

If i run the above query on my database it returns the one order above however as you can see in my code above the collection is empty.

If i change the date of the order to be `2019-08-06 16:34:21` (one hour in the future) the code then returns a collection with one item. It looks like it has something to do with the timezone somwehere? Maybe DST (Daylight Saving Time)?

*EDIT*

Here is some more information about the `$lsDate` variable.

`$lsDate` comes from a customer attribute. I store the date as so:

```
 $newDate = new \DateTime();
 $customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date', $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

And get the date as so:

```
$lsDate = $customer->getCustomAttribute('ls_start_date')->getValue();
```

Comment: How do you get that query out of your collection? it should at least also have a `AND customer_id = 123 order by created_at desc LIMIT 10` from your code, which it does not in your query. To be sure you get the real query out of your collection you should probably invoke the `->load()` function on it before printing the SQL out

Comment: Take care that you have a set on `ls_start_date` and a get on `ls_stamp_date`. So not the same attribute :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To start with, maybe we need a general Magento Date handling explanation.**

Magento intend all its dates to be saved in DB in GMT.
The reason for this design choice is quite simple: Magento allows you to configure multi-store that could be in multiples timezones.

Let's imagine I have a Magento with 3 stores, that I do operate from London.
Here are my store:

- My Londonian store, configured in `Europe/London`; this is also my Main Store configuration
- A store for Japan, configured in `Asia/Tokyo` timezone
- A store for north America, configured with timezone `America/New_York`

And now, let's take a business case were I do promise my customer that *"We deliver in 48 hour, worldwilde, based on the timezone of the capital city of the country you live in."*.

Then I get 3 orders, ones for each stores, all of them on the 1st of May at 16:15.
That would be extremly unconveniant for me, in the admin, to have all the three orders stated as placed on the 1st May at 16:15, to fulfill what I promise to my customer , because I would have to do crazy calculation based on the store I see in the admin grid of the orders.

The best for me would be to see

1. One order placed on **1st May at 16:15, in the Londonian store**
2. One order placed on **30rd April at 20:15, in the Tokyo store**
3. One order placed on **1st May at 21:15, in the New York store**

Magento, in order to do that, would retrieve the date in GMT from the database and then just apply the current sotre timezone to the date.
*Quite easy.*

Imagine the complexity it would have be if they did store timezoned dates in the database... Magento would need to store both the date AND the timezone and do conversions back and forth or timezones computation for any single date you have to display.
*Pretty crazy job to do.*

So your best bet, in order to follow Magento's way of working would be to store your dates in the database in GMT, and so to create your customer date this way:

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;   

class CustomerLsDate {
    private $dateTimeFactory; 

    public function __construct(DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory) {
        $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory;
    }

    public function setLsDate(Customer $customer): CustomerLsDate {
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date', $this->dateTimeFactory->create()->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to query on this date, just use it as is.
If you want to diplsay it to someone, in the store timezone, then:

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class CustomerLsDate {
    private $timezone;

    public function __construct(TimezoneInterface $timezone) {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }

    public function getLsDate(Customer $customer): string {
        $date = $this->timezone->date(
            new \DateTime(
                $customer->getCustomAttribute('ls_start_date')->getValue(),
                new \DateTimeZone('GMT')
            )
        );

        Zend_Debug::dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }  
}
```

That would really be the approach fitting most with Magento philosophy

Full `CustomerLsDate` class:

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;   

class CustomerLsDate {
   private $dateTimeFactory; 
   private $timezone;

   public function __construct(DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory, TimezoneInterface $timezone) {
       $this->timezone = $timezone;
       $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory;
   }

   public function setLsDate(Customer $customer): CustomerLsDate {
       $customer->setCustomAttribute(
           'ls_start_date', 
           $this->dateTimeFactory->create()->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       );

       return $this;
   }

   public function getLsDate(Customer $customer): string {
       $date = $this->timezone->date(
           new \DateTime(
               $customer->getCustomAttribute('ls_start_date')->getValue(),
               new \DateTimeZone('GMT')
           )
       );

       Zend_Debug::dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
       return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }  
}
```

---

Rick James have [part of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434847/2123530).

Since `created_at` is a [`timestamp`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/db_schema.xml#L225) and that a default connection to MySQL will [apply the server timezone to a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602038/2123530), your manual query works.

But now if you go like Magento and do

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00'; 
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`grand_total`, `main_table`.`created_at` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`created_at` >= '2019-08-06 15:33:21');
```

Your query won't return any result like your Magento collection does.
The `time_zone` setting of Magento is done in their default PDO adapter implementation here:

```
/**
 * Creates a PDO object and connects to the database.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception
 * @throws \Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
 */
protected function _connect()
{
    // extra unrelated code comes here...

    // As we use default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP type columns we need to set GMT timezone
    $this->_connection->query("SET time_zone = '+00:00'");

    // extra unrelated code comes here...
}
```

*Source:* [Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2a62f1ce0291c1d44f40ff020e44ee4f793ee557/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L416)

From there on, your answer lies in where your variable `$lsDate` is coming from and if you are able to know its timezone, in order to translate it back to GMT, to have the correct GMT date to give to your collection filter.

For example, if you know that your timezone is `'Europe/London'` you can do

```
$date = new \DateTime('2019-08-06 15:33:21', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // echoes 2019-08-06 14:33:21
```

And from your edit, when you do create a `new \DateTime()` you will get the a `DateTime` bound to the timezone of your server.

---

So based on your liking you can either save the date in your custom customer field in GMT, or save the timezone as well as the date.

### 1. Saving the date in GMT in the customer

Either the PHP way

```
$newDate = new \DateTime('now',new \DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date', $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

And you'll end up having a GMT date on you customer `ls_start_date`

Or you can also do it more Magento way, with DI:

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory;    

class Whatever {
   private $dateTimeFactory; 

   public function __construct(DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory) {
       $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory;
   }

   public function assignThatLsDate($customer) {
       $customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date', $this->dateTimeFactory->create()->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
   }
}
```

### 2. Saving the date in local timezone in the customer

```
$newDate = new \DateTime();
$customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date', $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$customer->setCustomAttribute('ls_start_date_timezone', $newDate->getTimezone ());
```

Then

```
$from = new \DateTime(
    $customer->getCustomAttribute('ls_start_date')->getValue(),
    $customer->getCustomAttribute('ls_start_date_timezone')->getValue()
)->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'));

// query to your collection is unchanged
```

Comment: I defiantly think your on the right track here. I have updated my question to give a little more detail on the $lsDate variable.

Comment: @GlenRobson edited with some more input, will have to have a look for the 3rd option though

Comment: Thanks for the update! Ill give the first option a go and see if that works. I would much prefer option 3 but from my research you cannot store timestamps as an attribute.

Comment: @GlenRobson more insight in a re-editted answer. Now what I am still missing is the context really. When and why are you creating this date? Is it the customer clicking a button to set that `lsDate`? Is it something in an event from some other Model? Or else?

Comment: Very detailed and well documented answer I have accepted so thank you. One question I have that you may be able to answer is the reason behind storing dates in GMT and not UTC?

Comment: Context is that the date gets set on an event (a form being filled in) and there forward I need to calculate order average based on previous orders after the date I save.

Comment: @GlenRobson the reason is explained in the first part of the revised answer: I am on store 1, you are on store 2. If I would be to store the date on store 1 TZ, I would have to store both the date and the TZ and do crazy computation. When storing eveythig on GMT means I can idempotently fetch a date from the DB then apply the current store TZ

Comment: Ah sorry I missred your question :) Well UTC == GMT (see https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html). GMT being the timzeone, UTC not being a timezone. In PHP you can use both `new \DateTimeZone('UTC')` ==  `new \DateTimeZone('GMT')`

Answer (score 2):

(too complex for a Comment; *may* lead to an answer.)

In MySQL, do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%zone%";  -- looking for how the timezone is set

SHOW CREATE TABLE ...  -- looking for datatypes used
```

In particular, is `created_at` a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: **Does** lead to the answer, I would say