# Liquibase & MySQL 5.7 timestamp column modification problem

Tags: mysql, liquibase, mysql-5.7

I have a column called `updated_time` it has a `timestamp` data type assigned:

```
`updated_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The problem is that currently, this column supports a second precision. I need it to be able to store a millisecond precision.

So, I have prepared a following Liquibase changeset:

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "1",
        "changes": [
          {
            "modifyDataType": {
              "columnName": "updated_time",
              "newDataType": "timestamp(3)",
              "tableName": "mytable"
            },
            "addDefaultValue": {
              "columnDataType": "timestamp(3)",
              "columnName": "updated_time",
              "defaultValueComputed": "current_timestamp(3)",
              "tableName": "mytable"
            },
            "addNotNullConstraint": {
              "columnDataType": "timestamp(3)",
              "columnName": "updated_time",
              "tableName": "mytable"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this changeset always fails.

Here is the reason:

```
2019-11-08 00:57:28.624  WARN [] 99326 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set ...
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'updated_time' [Failed SQL: (1067) ALTER TABLE maas.mytable MODIFY updated_time timestamp(3)]
```

I saw some posts regarding the fact that there were some changes to the `timestamp` data type in version 5.7. That, by default, I cannot assign a non-zero (null) value to the `timestamp` column. And, in order, to get it fixed, I'd have to make some changes to the server config itself. 
Let's imagine that I have a limited access to the server and I can't simply go and modify the config, is there an elegant way of working around this issue in Liquibase?

Comment: Have you tried using `datetime(3)` instead of `timestamp(3)`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Timestamp fits better based on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql

Comment: according to that thread - yes. But what about your own needs?

Comment: to be honest with you, I need that column to store epoch value. So, I think `bigint` is the best fit. But I do not know how to modify the type of the column and convert data from `timestamp` to `bigint` in one changeset. If there is a way to do it, I would go with that approach.
Otherwise, I'd keep it a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert `timestamp` to `bigint`, then you can do it the following way:

- create a new column, e.g. `bigint_date`;
- populate it with bigint values from your current `timestamp_date` column;
- drop your `timestamp_date` column;

Liquibase changeSets may look like this:

```
<changeSet id="foo1" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="bigint_date"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Add new column</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="your_table">
        <column name="bigint_date" type="bigint(13)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="foo2" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="bigint_date"/>
        <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="timestamp_date"/>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Populate it with bigint values from your current "timestamp_date" column</comment>
    <update tableName="your_table">
        <column name="bigint_date" valueComputed="SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_date) FROM your_table"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="foo3" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="timestamp_date"/>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Drop your "timestamp_date" column</comment>
    <dropColumn tableName="your_table" columnName="timestamp_date"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="foo4" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="bigint_date"/>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Update NULL values</comment>
    <update tableName="your_table">
        <column name="bigint_date" valueComputed="UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"/>
        <where>bigint_date IS NULL</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, I am tailoring that changeset, but in json. I'll report back soon.

Comment: It works fine, the only thing is left: how do I set the default value to my new bigint column to current timestamp? Is there a way?

Comment: adding something like `defaultValueComputed=“UNIX_TIMESTAMP()”` to the `<column>` tag of the `foo1` changeSet should do it

Comment: That function is allowed on selects, I tried to set it as default, no-go

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. I've updated my answer with `foo4` changeSet. It'll populate all NULL values (if there're any) of `bigint_date` with current timestamp. I guess you'll have to populate `bigint_date` with values in your code for future records.

Comment: All of my values are non-nulls already. I just wanted to add a default value that would set it to the current epoch if the app hasn't provided it. I read that some people are implementing a trigger for it, but it seems too much, way too involved. I'll just make sure that the application code always sets it.
Thanks for your help!