# how to test date and datetime with mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

My table is using a datetime `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)` and i need to display today's entries.

my code is only :

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     table 
WHERE    date = '$date' 
ORDER    BY score DESC
```

with

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

well, as expected it doesnt work :| you guys have a solution here ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following from Pascal Martin, you could extract the date part from the date+time field:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = '2009-12-19'
```

[Source: MySQL - Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Be aware however, that this query will not use an index on your date+time field, if you will be having one. ([Stack Overflow: How does one create an index on the date part of DATETIME field in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/))

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, with a solution like this one, in which there is a calculation on the "date" column, that calculation/conversion will have to be made on every line of the table -- ruining the chance of using the index that might have been set on the "date" column.

Comment: @Pascal: Yes, I think so. I've added the clarification in my answer... In the meantime, I am checking how MySQL handles this, for curiosity's sake.

Comment: @Daniel : OK ;; thanks for the precision :-) And I'm curious about it too, just to know if what I think is actually true or not ^^

Comment: @Pascal: Looks like you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/. Your solution is the way to go when you require the use of an index.

Comment: @Daniel : thanks for the search, the update, and the link :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your date is "2009-12-19" (or something like that, depending on the day), which is interpreted as "2009-12-19 00:00:00".

In your database, you probably don't have any date that's exactly equal to that one, by the second : your dates are like "2009-12-19 12:15:32".

A solution is to compare like this :

```
select *
from table
where date >= '2009-12-19'
    and date < '2009-12-20'
```

Which will be interpreted as :

```
select *
from table
where date >= '2009-12-19 00:00:00'
    and date < '2009-12-20  00:00:00'
```

And, if you don't want to do the math to get the date of the following date, you can use the `adddate` function :

```
select *
from table
where date >= '2009-12-19'
    and date < adddate('2009-12-19', interval 1 day)
```

So, in your case, something like this should do the trick :

```
select *
from table
where date >= '$date'
    and date < adddate('$date', interval 1 day)
order by score desc
```

Comment: isn't there a more beautiful option to write that ?
thx for the tips anyway, that would have took some thinking

Comment: Hu ; we don't agree on the definition of "beautiful", I suppose -- at least, I don't think this looks "ugly", but, well... ;; an advantage of this solution is that it should use the index you have on the "date" column, if you have any on that one (and maybe you should) -- while a solution that converts the "date" column or does a calculation on it will remove the abolity to use an index.

Comment: what do you mean by index ?
and by beautiful, I find the solution of Daniel Vassallo more clean

Comment: Heu... 600 characters won't be enough to explain what an index is, actually ^^ But you can take a look at this page of the manual, as a start : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to format the data when you select it:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dateformat FROM table
WHERE dateformat = '$date' ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing datetime and date expression, that is why its not working. Use Date() method to return the date part from datetime and then do the comparison. WHERE DATE(date) = '$date' should do. You might have to use aliases to handle this name collision.