# How do I add an index to a column that is datetime?

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate**
>   [How does one create an index on the date part of DATETIME field in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql)

In mysql. It's a date column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one create an index on the date part of DATETIME field in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You do it in the same way as you would for any other column type:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tblname_columnname
ON tbl_name (columnname)
```

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more information and other options.

Comment: If I create this index on my master, will it get replicated over to my slave?

Comment: @alex: I have no idea, but you can check by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname` on your slave and see if the index is present or not.