# MySQL - Combining 2 queries that have different SET and WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

A while ago @Richard Harris [gave a great answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641970/how-do-i-combine-two-update-statements-in-one-mysql-query), but I believe my situation is slightly different.

As you can see I have 2 consecutive UPDATE statements targeting the same table and fields but with different SET and  WHERE clauses.

```
$this->db->query("
UPDATE user_profiles
SET    reputation = reputation + 15
WHERE  user_id = $answer_author_id;
");

$this->db->query("
UPDATE user_profiles
SET    reputation = reputation + 2
WHERE  user_id = $user_id;
");
```

I wonder if this can be combined into a single query, or if this requires further normalization. Also, are these consecutive queries too inefficient? If not, I wouldn't bother trying to combine into a single query.

Your thoughts on this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
UPDATE user_profiles
SET    reputation = reputation + 
           case when user_id = $answer_author_id then 15
                when user_id = $user_id then 2
                else 0
           end
WHERE  user_id = $answer_author_id or user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: thanks again @derek ;) -- any idea re efficiency of this solution vs. 2 queries? just curious in case you've ever benchmarked this kind of situation

Comment: just did a quick benchmark check (averaged 5 server responses for your code vs. '2 queries') using my DB software via SSH -- results: your code (ave. 64.1 ms) -- 2 queries (ave. 162.6 ms) -- pretty impressive no?

Answer (score 1):

The solution actually isn't terribly different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641970/how-do-i-combine-two-update-statements-in-one-mysql-query#4641982), just a tad more nested.

```
UPDATE my_table SET reputation = 
    IF( USER_ID = $user_id, REPUTATION + 2, REPUTATION + 15 ) 
        WHERE USER_ID IN ( $user_id, $answer_author_id );
```

Comment: thx - i think i'll try derek's code for the meanwhile since it's a bit more readable (for maintenance sake)

Comment: Suit yourself, they boil down to the same query either way.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE user_profiles
SET    reputation = reputation + IF(user_id=$answer_author_id,15,2)
WHERE  user_id = $answer_author_id OR user_id = $answer_author_id;

This works, but I recommend using 2 queries simply for code readability, unless efficiency is super important.