# Optimise SQL query for the report

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-optimization

This is SQL query I wrote, it work fine but it is slow.

```
SELECT D.Username, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Sales, 
        COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM dairy as D
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile 
        WHERE source = 'Network' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1309561200
 group by D.Username order by TOTAL DESC
```

As you can see it count number of Yes, No, Other and the matching MobileNo (`D.MobileNo = S.mobile`) sale.

I have tried adding index to type, username, mobile, MobileNO, CheckDate and source - the performance did not improve much.

Comment: what the format of CheckDate?

Comment: can u change the query to check against CheckDate without using function, because with this function wrap the index of this column not so effective, look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE diary`? And the same for sales? Then, the output of your SELECT, but with `EXPLAIN` in front of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points to notice in your query:

#### 1. There's a chance the `LEFT JOIN` is giving you performance issues.

However, you need it, since it is possible that there are `D.MobileNo` values that will not be present in `SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales`. Any other work around (yes, there are options) will most likely decrease performance. But your performance might be improved by observing the next items.

#### 2. Make sure you have indexes in the key columns:

- D.type
- S.mobile
- D.MobileNo
- D.Username
- D.Source
- D.CheckDate

#### 3. You might be having problems with filtering by `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate)`

This might be the key issue. You might be having problems with filtering by `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate)` instead of `CheckDate`, specially if `Dairy` has a large amount of records. The problem is that even if you have an index for `CheckDate`, it will probably not be used because of the function. Try to filter by `CheckDate` itself.

Comment: Thanks for SQL query, it dont seem to work - im not getting any result.

Comment: Sorry, its working now, my mistake...  but the result appear to be different... It is not adding up properly.

Comment: Is it possible that there are D.MobileNo that will contain a value not in `SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is time critical it can also make sense to store more data.

Here this means that you add INT columns for YesValue, NoValue, OtherValue and fill them with 0 or 1 in your application. By doing this you can remove the case calculations from your SELECT-part.

Also please post all indexes currently available and as the comments say the CREATE-statement for the table.