# MySQL enforce uniqueness on year part of date

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to enforce uniqueness in MySQL on a pair of columns  X,Y  where X is Date and Y is Integer.  I need uniqueness to apply to Year(X),Y.  using UNIQUE it is easy to do this on the pair of columns, but I don't see how I can add the constraint by extracting the Year part of the date.

Comment: No. You can only apply uniqueness to an entire field. you'd have to have a separate integer field for the year, and unique that entire field. Maybe someday when mysql supports proper constraints, you'll be able to do this, but not today.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql

Comment: Well, you can enforce the constraint in the query itself, or I suppose you could have a separate table storing valid years.

Comment: wrong slot huh Strawberry? :p

Comment: Pesky mobile phones

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/95295/2077386 :  

"In the meantime you can use character columns for storing DATETIME values as strings, with only first N characters being indexed. With some careful usage of triggers in MySQL 5 you can create a reasonably robust solution based on this idea."

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 5.7 you could use generated tables to concatinate two columns together and define the generated column as unique.

CREATE TABLE unq (mydate DATE, myint INT, mydateint CHAR(30) AS (CONCAT(mydate,myint)) UNIQUE);