# How to set uniqueness for two field relation_id and date_only (yyyy-mm-dd) in MySQL database

Tags: database

> I am creating a website for gaming website and there I have problem to set unique combination for two value.
>       
>       **table_1 :**
>
> id (Primary)
>
> game_name
>
> **table_2 :**
>
> id (Primary)
>
> game_id (INDEX) --- relation with table_1-id
>
> result
>
> create_on (timestamp)
>
> I want to set constraint between game_id and created_on(date_only). because here i will update
>   a result value for each game per day and here don't want to get double
>   entry in same day. is this possible to set constraint in database?

Comment: You need to tell us which database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) you are using.

Comment: I am using MySQL database @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: You did not get my point ! you may please read my question again to understand that I am talking about to make unique combination of  game_id and partial timestamp (Y-m-d) instead of full timestamp (Y-m-d H:i:s). here I have full timestamp in my database all time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql