# How to make MySQL use functional index on a datetime column?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, innodb, functional-index

Say I'm running MySQL 8 with a table `data` containing about 1M rows. And I want to filter a `datetime` column on `date` a range (using a date index).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `rowId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,                               -- <-- datetime column for a date index
  `created_date` DATE AS (cast(`created` as date)) NOT NULL, -- <-- generated date column
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowId`),
  INDEX (`created`),                                         -- <-- datetime index w/ cardinality ~ 1M 
  INDEX (`created_date`)                                     -- <-- date index w/ cardinality of 1250
  INDEX `created_cast` ((cast(`created` as date)))           -- <-- functional "date" index w/ cardinality of 1250
  --     ^ I WANT TO USE THIS INDEX, BUT DON'T KNOW HOW
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then let's filter rows only from 2018, let's say:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data
WHERE created >= CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND created < CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE);
-- Query time: 0.16 s
-- EXPLAIN shows: key: created, Using where; Using index
-- Uses the whole datetime index w/ cardinality of ~ 1M 


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data 
WHERE created_date BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE);
-- Query time: 0.09 s
-- EXPLAIN shows: key: created_date, Using where; Using index
-- Uses the date index w/ cardinality of 1250


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data
WHERE CAST(created AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE);
-- Query time: 0.35 s, that's slow!
-- EXPLAIN shows: key: NULL, Using where
-- Doesn't use any index at all!
```

#### Is there a way to use this functional index?

The queries above use either `created` (datetime) or `created_date` (date from generated column) indexes.

Is there a way to **use functional index** `created_cast` directly? I've even tried with `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX`, but no luck.

Thank you all :)

Comment: ? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE created BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-01 00:00:00'` (I guess I must have missed the point of the question)

Comment: Point of the question: Is there a good / effective way to use generated (functional) index instead of a generated column?

Comment: But wouldn't you just do what I've done instead?

Comment: That works pretty much like the first query of my example. It's not the fastest, because it uses a datetime index of over 1 million rows cardinality. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Strawberry, An index on dates (generated column) has cardinality of 1250 and works faster. I want to make use of that generated index (without generated column). It has the right cardinality, but I don't seem to be able to make a query use it.

Comment: Does `DATE(created)` work better than `(cast(`created` as date))`?

Comment: @RickJames, nope, works about the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your queries and remove the `CAST`
and use the he generated column, as you have no conversion in it, but it needs space.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE data (created datetime,
> `created_date` DATE AS (cast(`created` as date)) NOT NULL,  INDEX testin (`created`),                                         -- <-- datetime index w/ cardinality ~ 1M 
>   INDEX (`created_date`))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERt INTO data (created) VALUEs('2018-02-01'),('2018-02-01'),('2018-02-01'),('2018-02-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data
>     WHERE YEAR(`created`) = 2018;
> ```

> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data FORCE INDEX (testin)
>     WHERE DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31';
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
> ```

> ```
>     EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data FORCE INDEX (testin) 
>     WHERE DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                   
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :---- | :------------ | :----- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | null       | index | null          | testin | 6       | null |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data 
>     WHERE created BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:49:59';
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data 
>     WHERE created BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:49:59';
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                   
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :---- | :------------ | :----- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | null       | index | testin        | testin | 6       | null |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf701ef1673db57fb4bdf40adfe98e50)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `WHERE YEAR(`created`) = 2018` seems very elegant, but it uses the datetime index and still runs 0.225 s slow over my 1M dataset. Second solution, `WHERE DATE(created) BETWEEN ...` uses no index and runs 0.653 s slow and `WHERE DATE(created_date) BETWEEN ...` uses date index (from a generated column), and runs at 0.150 s. Neither of those use that functional index.

Comment: see my changed answer and try again please

Comment: This uses the datetime index and runs at 0.424 s... I've tried with `FORCE INDEX (created_date)` which only works for `WHERE created_date ...`, and also `FORCE INDEX (created_cast)`, which doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to use that functional index (`INDEX `created_cast` ((cast(`created` as date)))`). Without the use of a generated column, which clutter the schema.

Comment: yes i understand, see my last approach, but doubt that will improve that much, because here als the where has priority

Comment: this works the same about my first query, still using the 1M index... But thank you for trying :-)